# Как верно реализовать автозаполнение формы с подсказками Google Pay?

Tags: html, вёрстка, google-play

Дано: есть форма для веба, при заполнении формы с мобильного , а именно вводе номера кредитной карты - должна выскакивать подсказка, что можете подключить оплату google play (как на макете).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался реализовать с помощью атрибутов автозаполнения:

```
<form>
<label for="frmCCNum">Card Number</label>
```

и по этой [статье:](http://4xpro.ru/profblog/google-pay-2)

но так ничего и не получилось. Есть ли какие туториалы или готовые решения, как выполнить данную задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Данная задача решается с помощью

```
autocomplete="cc-number"
```

если данных по карте в аккаунте нет - значит и предложения оплатить не будет.